# SQL Server 2014 - Add Node inherits wrong configuration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, clustering

I'm setting up a simple 2-node failover cluster with SQL 2014 on Server 2012 R2 in Core mode (no GUI). I have the cluster configured with identical machines, and I have the first node configured and working.

When I go to add the second node however, the wrong configuration information is used. Specifically, the shared and instance binary locations point to the OS drive (I installed them on a different drive on node 1). I tried manually specifying the locations in the configuration file, but setup won't accept these parameters when the install mode is `AddNode`. Did I do something wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug/feature. It was discussed previously on SQL Server Central http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1578488-2799-1.aspx where Ed Vassie said:

> Put it another way... On an ADDNODE install you cannot specify the
>   location for the SQL binaries, they always go to the system drive.

Ed Vassie is a reliable source as the original developer of FineBuild, a tool specifically for rolling out repeatable installs of SQL Server including in clustering mode. He lives and breathes this part of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this problem:

Uninstalled everything, ran setup with `/ACTION=PrepareFailoverCluster` on both nodes first (which allows you to choose the binary locations), and then ran it again with `/ACTION=CompleteFailoverCluster` on one of the nodes. It takes three runs of the installer instead of two, but it solves the issue.

The only limitation is that you have to be setting up a new cluster and know how many nodes you need ahead of time. Prepare cannot be run after Complete has run.